# AWS Layer RequestEntityTooLargeException Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, layer

I am trying to deploy a Layer, with the size of 99MB, and I am getting this error.

```
│ Error: Error creating lambda layer: RequestEntityTooLargeException:
│   status code: 413, request id: 5a87d055-ba71-47bb-8c60-86d3b00e8dfc
│
│   with aws_lambda_layer_version.aa,
│   on layers.tf line 68, in resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "aa":
│   68: resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "aa" {
```

This is the .tf

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "aa" {
  filename   = "custom_layers/aa/a.zip"
  layer_name = "aa"

  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.8"]
}
```

The zip is in the right location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [AWS Lambda quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), you cannot have a deployment package (.zip file archive) with size more than:

> 50 MB (zipped, for direct upload)
>
> 250 MB (unzipped)
>
> This quota applies to all the files you upload, including layers and
> custom runtimes.
>
> 3 MB (console editor)

There's also a paragraph in the AWS Lambda docs for your [exact error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html):

> General: Error occurs when calling the UpdateFunctionCode Error: An
> error occurred (RequestEntityTooLargeException) when calling the
> UpdateFunctionCode operation
>
> When you upload a deployment package or layer archive directly to
> Lambda, the size of the ZIP file is limited to 50 MB. To upload a
> larger file, store it in Amazon S3 and use the S3Bucket and S3Key
> parameters.

You should try to do one of the following:

1. Split your current lambda layer into multiple layers
2. Upload the layer zip to S3, and specify the Object in your terraform lambda config